# LinkedIn Manage Organization users' role API issue

Tags: linkedin-api

While trying to update an organization user's role using LinkedIn API:[organization access control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-access-control-by-role?view=li-lms-2022-09&tabs=http#request-direct-sponsored-content-poster-role) following error occured:
[LinkedIn page error response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUlzU.png)

API request:

```
const encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent(accountId);
  const { data } = await axios.put(
    `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationAcls/(organization:${encodedUrl},role:DIRECT_SPONSORED_CONTENT_POSTER,roleAssignee:${userId})`,
    {
      state: 'REQUESTED',
      role: 'DIRECT_SPONSORED_CONTENT_POSTER',
      roleAssignee: userId,
      organization: accountId,
    },
    setAccessToken(accessToken)
  );
```

Encountered similar issue with LinkedIn Ads manage organization user's update API:
[LinkedIn Ads error response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkwHV.png)

Postman collection for LinkedIn Ads: [postman collection](https://www.postman.com/linkedin-developer-apis/workspace/linkedin-marketing-solutions-versioned-apis/folder/17563548-fca6fef5-d217-4e65-bfe7-a4070aa54f1a?ctx=documentation)

How can I resolve this issue and update a user role?

Comment: In the URL, you have "encodedUrl". Is that a typo or are you actually passing in a URL? It should be the organization URN, which would be in a format like "urn:li:organization:{id}".

Comment: @Ashavan The documentation suggests to use the organization URN encoded. 
[documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-access-control-by-role?view=li-lms-2022-09&tabs=http#request-direct-sponsored-content-poster-role)

`PUT https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationAcls/(organization:{encoded organization URN},role:DIRECT_SPONSORED_CONTENT_POSTER,roleAssignee:{person URN})`.

Comment: Exactly. You indicated above that you were passing in an encoded URL, which is different from an encoded URN.

Comment: @Ashavan that is actually the encoded URN itself. The variable name might have made you confused.